# How should I store a two column table with duplicated first column entries?

Tags: java, arrays, storage

In my program there are a 72 paths (numbered from 1 to 72). In the program I need to retrieve adjacent paths, and then check the ownership of these two paths. The paths range from 2 adjacent paths to 4. For example path 1 has adjacent paths 2 and 7; whereas, path 13 has adjacent paths 8, 12, 14, 21. These path relationships are constant.

I would like to write a method `path.getAdjacent(int pathNum)` that would return a `int[]` containing all adjacent paths. This way I could make a for loop that checks each the owners for each adjacent path.

How should I store and access the path relationship data so that it may be efficiently retrieved by the method `path.getAdjacent()`?

Comment: What language? If Java, a `Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>` would probably be most suitable.

Comment: Yes, it is java. I am relatively new to the language. How would I implement such a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

davide answered my question:

Use a `Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>`